# ListView.builder throwing RedorBox error when setting scrollDirection to Axis.horizontal

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using a `ListView.builder` and a `Gridview.builder` and need to make `ListView` horizontal but when I set its `scrollDirection` property it throws error (picture attached)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  List<String> litems = ["Hello", "how"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                itemCount: 18,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CategoryButton(title: "title");
                }),
            GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 18,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('Some text more');
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2knH.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `ListView.builder` directly to the column widget. Column and its parent SingleChildScrollView widgets have infinity height and width. You should set width and height for the ListView.builder widget or warp inside the `Expanded` widget. I have resolved it by setting the height and widget. Find the codes below.

```
class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  final List<String> litems = ["Hello", "how"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[_buildListView(), _buildGridView()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  GridView _buildGridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 18,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text('Some text more');
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      width: deviceWidth,
      height: 150.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: 18,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("title"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]